# Recognize docker container from host machine browser

Tags: docker

I have 2 dockers in a net: web and backend
When I access "web" from the host machine (http://web:3000) it works.
"web" have a "test connection" button to the backend machine, which just tries to access a static page on the backend machine (http://backend:80/isAlive)

But since the call is made from the browser, and the browser is on the host machine, then the "backend" hostname can not be resolved.

I can fix this by editing my host file to so that "backend" will be resolved to localhost, but is there a more intelligent way to do this?

Comment: Could you please send your docker-compose ? I guess you should bind them in the same network [https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/]

Comment: I've set up both of them using --net=MyNetwork. The problem is not between the containers, but from the host itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should strongly consider setting up a separate container acting as a reverse proxy forwarding requests to different containers using virtual hosts.

```
backend.foo.bar  -> talks to backend container
web.foo.bar      -> talks to web container
```

If you don't want do configure dns you can just map those names to localhost in your hosts file for now.

The quickest way to get this working is using [jwilder/nginx](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). When you get it working you can go into the container and look at the generated config file for nginx and learn a fair bit in case you want to set this up manually in the future.

Again: This means that the `jwilder/nginx` container is the only one that maps a port to localhost. The other containers are proxied through it.